# Reference fields in cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to reference different fields from the same cursor, but I can't choose which name I'll display.
I already tried to put "... AS 'NAME1"

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;

DECLARE
CURSOR GET_TOOLKITS
    IS
        SELECT PROJ.NAME -- first name
             , PROJ.SHORT_NAME  
         , SNAP.NAME SNAP_NAME --second name
         , BRAN.NAME AS BRANCH_NAME -- third name
         , SNAP.SNAPSHOT_ID
         , PROJ.PROJECT_ID
         , TRUNC(PROJ.CREATED_ON)
          FROM LSW_SNAPSHOT SNAP
         , LSW_PROJECT PROJ 
               , LSW_BRANCH BRAN
         WHERE 1=1 
           AND SNAP.PROJECT_ID = PROJ.PROJECT_ID
           AND SNAP.BRANCH_ID = BRAN.BRANCH_ID
           AND PROJ.IS_TOOLKIT = 'T'
           AND SNAP.IS_ARCHIVED = 'F'
           AND SNAP.NAME IS NOT NULL;

CURSOR GET_SNAPSHOTS
    IS
        SELECT PROJ.NAME
         , PROJ.SHORT_NAME
         , SNAP.NAME SNAP_NAME 
         , BRAN.NAME AS BRANCH_NAME
         , SNAP.SNAPSHOT_ID
         , PROJ.PROJECT_ID
         , TRUNC(PROJ.CREATED_ON)
          FROM LSW_SNAPSHOT SNAP
         , LSW_PROJECT PROJ
         , LSW_BRANCH BRAN
         WHERE 1=1 
           AND SNAP.PROJECT_ID = PROJ.PROJECT_ID
           AND SNAP.BRANCH_ID = BRAN.BRANCH_ID
           AND PROJ.IS_TOOLKIT = 'F'
           AND SNAP.IS_ARCHIVED = 'F'
           AND SNAP.NAME IS NOT NULL;

    SET_TOOLKITS GET_TOOLKITS%ROWTYPE;
    SET_SNAPSHOTS GET_SNAPSHOTS%ROWTYPE;

  V_COUNT NUMBER:=0;

BEGIN   
    OPEN GET_TOOLKITS;

    LOOP
        FETCH GET_TOOLKITS INTO SET_TOOLKITS;
        EXIT WHEN GET_TOOLKITS%NOTFOUND;
    V_COUNT := V_COUNT+1;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SET_TOOLKITS.NAME --ref first name
                      || ' '
                      || SET_TOOLKITS.NAME --ref second name
                      || ' '
                      || SET_TOOLKITS.NAME --ref third name
                      || ' ');

    END LOOP;
END;
```

And if anyone can help me with that condition "IS_TOOLKIT" to dynamically change I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this one:

```
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SET_TOOLKITS.NAME --ref first name
                  || ' '
                  || SET_TOOLKITS.SNAP_NAME --ref second name
                  || ' '
                  || SET_TOOLKITS.BRANCH_NAME --ref third name
                  || ' ');
```